# Error when accessing pandas series by index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a piece of code:

```
texts = []
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    _text = ''
    for c in df.columns:
        _text += c + ':' + str(df[c][i]) + '<br>'
    texts.append (_text)
```

and I have the error of `ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` at the line `_text += c + ':' + str(df[c][i]) + '<br>'`.

I changed the `[i]` to all kinds of accessing functions I know: at, iat, loc, iloc but none of them works, they still have the same problem.

Comment: could you edit your question with some example so that I can find where the code goes wrong?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with simple dataframes. Please show an example.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: i inserted `iloc[i]` in line 5:

```
texts = []
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    _text = ''
    for c in df.columns:
        _text += c + ':' + str(df[c].iloc[i]) + '<br>'
    texts.append (_text)
```